# How to get the value.value property value from inspect tool in pywinauto

Tags: python, winforms, ui-automation, pywinauto

```
plcPid = application.process_from_module(module = "application.exe")    
wpfApp = Application(backend='uia').connect(process=plcPid)
wind = wpfApp.windows()
title = wind[0].get_properties()[u'texts'][0]    
handle = wpfApp.window(title = title) 
test = handle.child_window(title="FlexGrid", auto_id="grdCurrentOrder", control_type="Table")
print(test[u"Column 1 Row 4"].legacy_properties())
```

legacy properties: {'ChildId': 0, 'DefaultAction': '', 'Description': '', 'Help': '', 'KeyboardShortcut': '', 'Name': 'Row 4', 'Role': 10, 'State': 1, 'Value': ''}

print control identifiers and inspect tool are not giving same values using pywinauto.

i am trying to get the value out of the grid cell in windows forms of .Net application

here is the image from from inspect tool [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf4mt.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA4ba.png

legacy properties: {'ChildId': 0, 'DefaultAction': '', 'Description': '', 'Help': '',
'KeyboardShortcut': '', 'Name': 'Row 4', 'Role': 10, 'State': 1, 'Value': ''}